# How to provison AWS VPC for only a certain period of the day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc, static-ip-address

We're using AWS VPC to get our lambda functions to have a static IP address. The issue is that we only need the VPC during a certain period of the day when we do our imports but we're charged for the full 24 hours since it's always running.

Is there a way to schedule (Instance scheduler is not available in our region so I'm looking for an alternative) or programmatically (with SDK or something) provision/turn off the VPC so that we're only provisioning it (and being charged) during the hour or two that we're using it?

Or is there a smarter way to get our lambda functions to have a static IP? (Used [this](https://medium.com/@gboyegadada/aws-how-to-create-a-static-ip-address-using-a-nat-gateway-845c884aa4bd) guide to set it ̣up)

EDIT: I was actually think of NAT, since NAT is the one that's billed hourly but the same still stands, we only ever have use of it during one hour when we have scheduled imports.

Comment: You're not charged for the existence of a VPC or for non-invoked Lambda functions afaik. Are you referring to the cost of NAT?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, sorry I was thinking of NAT, it's billed hourly. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I have previously managed to attach an Elastic IP address to the ENI that Lambda creates in the VPC. If the Lambda function is attached to a **public subnet**, then it can actually reach the Internet without a NAT. However, this is not a guaranteed solution since Lambda might create multiple ENIs. Nonetheless, you might want to experiment with it. That way, you won't need to start/stop anything. The alternative is to create/delete the NAT as desired.

Comment: Nowadays Lamda doesn't create multiple ENI's anymore. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So taking into account what Azize said, it's possible to have a static outgoing IP address without using the NAT gateway?

Comment: As I said, you might want to experiment with it. It is not an official method and things might suddenly change, but it has worked for me in the past.